# User controls in winform application with mvp pattern

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, mvp

I'm developing winform application using MVP pattern. There are some user controls in my application which were created before. My question is: should I use MVP inside these controls? That is, do I have alter thier?

Comment: What MVP framework are you using for Winforms? Is it something you home-baked?

Comment: I not using any MVP Framework, it's only my own implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the http://webformsmvp.com/ implementation I'd say you should alter the existing controls and use MVP pattern inside.

The reason is the communication among user-controls should be consistent. eg, do you want it to look like this:

[image]

Or more elegant and uniform:

[image]